# How to query created_at for Yesterday with a specific timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Right now I have the following query:

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["guest = ? AND created_at >= ?", false , (Date.yesterday)]).count
```

Problem is yesterday on the rails/db server is GMT. And where I need the count it is calculated in PST.

How can I update the query above to find all User's created yesterday in the PST timezone?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
@from = (Time.zone.now - 1.day).beginning_of_day.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
@to   = (Time.zone.now).beginning_of_day.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
User.count(:conditions => ["created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?", @from, @to])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tweak for this, a subtle one - `Date.yesterday` uses `Date.current` which will use the time zone whereas `Date.today` doesn't. If you set your time zone to one where it's tomorrow already (e.g. Europe/Berlin as I type this) then you can get `Date.today == Date.yesterday:`

```
>> Time.zone = "Europe/London"
=> "Europe/London"
>> Date.today == Date.yesterday
=> false

>> Time.zone = "Europe/Berlin"
=> "Europe/Berlin"
>> Date.today == Date.yesterday
=> true
```

Using Date.current == Date.yesterday works as expected. This example is shown in irb so please try to find a way to put it in your rails app apropriately. **Note:** I am not showing the exact thing what you need as you have do some coding before to initialize time zone etc but just throwing some worthy bits.Hope this helps

Comment: great tip about internal use of `Date.current`

Comment: very interesting but now sure how to Update the query to solve the problem? Running Time.zone in rails c shows => (GMT+00:00) UTC, how can I run the query with PST?